# MYSQL Code first migrations

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

When running code first migrations with MySQL the migration completes successfully but as soon as context is accesses and i either try to fetch or add data i get an exception.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The underlying provider does not support the type 'nvarchar(max)'.

Automatic migrations work without any problem :(

Comment: Which provider do you use?

Comment: MYSQL.
I found the problem and it seems it was caused by migrations leftovers. Basically EF tried to match and MSSQL schema with MYSQL and failed.